# Flurry SDK for Android 2.1?

Tags: android, flurry

Is there a version of the Flurry SDK for Android 2.1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes the Flurry SDK works for Android 2.1. What you need to do is following. Sign up here: [www.flurry.com](http://www.flurry.com)

After this you'll have to create a new Project, than do following steps:

1. Add FlurryAgent.jar to your application's classpath

   - If you're using Eclipse, modify your Java Build Path, and choose Add External JAR... or use Gradle + Jcenter `compile 'com.flurry.android:analytics:6.2.0'`
   - If you're using the SDK tools directly, drop it into your libs folder and the ant task will   pick it up.
2. Configure AndroidManifest.xml

Required Permission:

```
android.permission.INTERNET
```

Required to send analytics data back to the flurry servers
Optional Permission:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
```

If your application has location permissions, analytics will track where your application is being used. Without this, only country level location information will be available. To disable detailed location reporting even when your app has permission, call `FlurryAgent.setReportLocation(false) before calling FlurryAgent.onStartSession()` and no detailed location information will be sent.
Specify a versionName attribute in the manifest to have data reported under that version name.

3.Add calls to onStartSession and onEndSession

Insert a call to `FlurryAgent.onStartSession(Context, String`), passing it a reference to a Context object (such as an Activity or Service), and your application's API key [YOURAPIKEYRIGHTHERE]. We recommend using the onStart method of each Activity in your application, and passing the Activity (or Service) itself as the Context object - passing the global Application context is not recommended.

```
public void onStart()
{
   super.onStart();
   FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, "YOURAPIKEYRIGHTHERE");
   // your code
}
```

Insert a call to `FlurryAgent.onEndSession(Context)` when a session is complete. We recommend using the onStop method of each Activity in your application. Make sure to match up a call to onEndSession for each call of onStartSession, passing in the same Context object that was used to call onStartSession

```
public void onStop()
{
   super.onStop();
   FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
   // your code
}
```

So long as there is any Context that has called onStartSession but not onEndSession, the session will be continued. Also, if a new Context calls onStartSession within 10 seconds of the last Context calling onEndSession, then the session will be resumed, instead of a new session being created. Session length, usage frequency, events and errors will continue to be tracked as part of the same session. This ensures that as a user transitions from one Activity to another in your application that they will not have a separate session tracked for each Activity, but will have a single session that spans many Activities. If you want to track Activity usage, we recommend using onEvent, described below. If you wish to change the window during which a session can be resumed, call `FlurryAgent.setContinueSessionMillis(long milliseconds)` before the first call to `FlurryAgent.onStartSession`.

If you wish to change the window during which a session can be resumed, call `FlurryAgent.setContinueSessionMillis(long milliseconds)` before the first call to `FlurryAgent.onStartSession`.

I hope I could help you!

Have a great day!

safari